# Hang 250 kg (550 lbs) on concrete wall

Tags: walls, load

I want to hang a 250 kg (550 lbs) water heater on the exterior wall (this mass includes the water). The system to attach it is included (two metal bars, attached with 2 screws each).

The concrete wall (poured concrete) looks thick and sturdy, but it makes me a little uncomfortable anyway. Could hanging such a heavy object damage the wall, or make it more likely that cracks will appear in a few years?

If so I have the option to set the water heater on a pedestal first, before screwing it to the wall. But that would need the water heater is at the same level of the pipe outputs, which would make it hard to install. Opinions appreciated.

EDIT : Adding more context, as suggested in the comment

- My question is really about whether I can hang 250 kg using 4 screws (and metal bars), or whether that's too much for the wall. My question is NOT about the fastener, or the mounting hardware (this is provided with the water heater, so I trust it is solid enough).
- I do not intend to use the other side of the wall.
- I don't have access to other elements. As far as I know, there is no joist at all. This is just concrete.
- It is for a simple 200L electrical, tanked water heater. 1.20 m high, and 56 cm of width and breadth.

Comment: You'll get better results here if you ask a more specific question with more facts about your specific situation.  Do you have access to the back side of the wall to install mounting hardware?  Do you have access to other structural elements such as interior joists that you might use to cantilever the mounting?  What do you want to do with the space underneath the water heater?    Are you asking if you can hang 250kg on concrete using 4 screws?   Its this a fastener question?  How big are the screws?  What fasteners are included?  You can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: The type of water heater will help and you say you have access to the other side. How thick is this wall? You don’t say if this is a tanked or a large tankless.  So we need dimensions, at first I would have said sure you can do this but depending on the answers to these questions I might say are you crazy..  more info needed.

Comment: Another question, perhaps harder to answer: what sort of concrete?   Just among blocks there's a huge range from aerated at one extreme to capable of carrying serious loads at the other.  I've had both in the same part of the same house, because the aerated ones won't support roofing joists without something to spread the load

Comment: Poured concrete or concrete _block_?

Comment: poured concrete. I will add it as well.

Comment: @EdBeal  Editing to add the answer

Comment: I know you don’t want to hear about the steel bracket or screws because they came with the unit, but I think you are misinterpreting what they are for. The bracket is NOT for wall mounting the unit. Rather, it’s an earthquake bracket. It’s used to keep the unit vertical during an earthquake. It’s not strong enough (and the screws are certainly not strong enough) to support that much water. However, it is strong enough to keep the unit vertical during an event.

Comment: Ah really... thanks for pointing that out. Following the answers here, I will use a pedestal in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your concern about putting it on a pedestal. Doesn't your plumbing need to match up with the inlet/outlet on the heater no matter how you mount the thing?

If you have fixed hard lines that you're trying to match up with, just build a pedestal to the proper height so its connections meet up with your existing lines, set the empty tank on it, use the included fasteners to *also* fasten it to the wall (overkill never hurts), then finish the plumbing connections.

If the lines need to run into the *bottom* of the tank (quite annoying, IMHO), build an open frame on which to set the heater *without* interfering with the location of the lines, then do as above.

If you've got flexible lines, then your pedestal height is mostly subject to how long a flexible line you've got/can get, and how high off the ground you want the tank. Again, follow installation from above.

Having something supporting the weight from below, whether wood, concrete block or steel seems to me to be the safest, surest way of doing it. Using the wall-mounting hardware provided by the manufacturer *in addition* simply adds to the security.

Comment: I think that’s a fair point. I will do that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Happy to help! Sometimes, it's just hard to see the forest for all the trees... :)

Comment: Yes, so many details, so many decisions !

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that the hardware is designed for masonry (concrete/brick/block). It is possible to hang a similar weight from a wood framed wall, using metal bars + screws. But the screws would be quite different for wood studs vs. masonry - use the wrong type of screws (on either type of wall) and you are looking for trouble.

Getting screws into concrete is a non-trivial task. A regular drill will **not** do it (at least not very quickly/easily). You need a hammer-drill or similar type of tool. There are some alternatives such as powder-actuated fasteners, but I have no experience with those.

All that being said, if you want some extra safety margin, you can put brackets underneath. Typically a steel triangle - one side under the load (so it supports underneath the whole load instead of just the back), one side on the wall (with at least two screws per bracket into the wall) and an angled brace between the two (which prevents it from just bending under the weight). [Something like](https://amzn.to/3qasmYz):

[image: brackets]

Answer (score 0):

How about using square steel tubing, maybe 1-1/2 inch, tight against the wall to transfer the weight to the ground, and then concrete fasteners all along its length into the wall.   It can extend far above the top of the tank so you have multiple fasteners with excellent leverage and all they are doing is preventing tipping.  You could probably just use tapcon screws without anchors this way.  They are not supporting (directly or cantilevered) the weight which instead is on the ground.  And the steel tube only interferes with 1-1/2 inches of space beneath the tank.

It's not that you cannot do this directly to the wall behind the tank with appropriate fasteners, it's just that it requires a lot more specialized knowledge and skill to do safely.   Look at [this document](http://allfasteners.com/media/entry/file/w/e/wedgeanchor_tds.pdf) for an indication of the kind of planning you need to do and then read lots more about concrete expansion anchors.